# Showing skipping mark in excel graph

Tags: excel, graph

I would like to add this little mark in Excel graph to show there are skipped value. Is this possible in excel? Or can you suggest me other program to draw this type of graph?

[image]

Comment: The starting number implies a group of skipped value's.